# How to separate and graph lines in array by a value in each line

Tags: python, datetime

I'm new to Python and am trying to pull data from a growing CSV, and create a live updating plot. I want to create two different x,y arrays depending on which antenna the data is coming through (one of the values in each line of data separated by commas). The data file looks like the following:

```html
TimeStamp, ReadCount, Antenna, Protocol, RSSI, EPC, Sensor
09/21/2016 15:24:40.560, 5499, 1, GEN2, -21, E036112D912508B3, 23.78,47.00,0.00,2.21, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:41.138, 5506, 1, GEN2, -9, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:41.623, 5513, 1, GEN2, -25, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:42.120, 5520, 1, GEN2, -18, E036112D912508B3, 23.78,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:42.633, 5527, 1, GEN2, -12, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,45.00,0.00,2.23, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:43.211, 5534, 1, GEN2, -9, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:43.744, 5541, 1, GEN2, -16, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
```

Code I have which successfully shows the graph, but just takes in all lines of data into one x,y set of arrays looks like the following:

```html
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from datetime import datetime
      
offset = -7.4954
slope = 0.9548

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#07000d')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='#07000d')

ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax1.spines['top'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax1.spines['left'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax1.spines['right'].set_color("#5998ff")
    
def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('SensorLog.csv','r').read()
    dataArray = graph_data.split('\n')

    xar=[]
    yar=[]
    
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if 'TimeStamp' not in eachLine: 
            if len(eachLine)>1:
                t,rc,ant,prot,rssi,epc,temp,ten,powr,unpowr,inf=(eachLine.split(','))         
                time = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
                clock = time.strftime('%I:%M')
                xs = matplotlib.dates.datestr2num(clock)
                hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y\n%I:%M:%S %p')

#                Convert tension
                tension = int(float(ten)*float(slope)+float(offset))
                
                xar.append(xs)
                yar.append(tension)
                
    ax1.clear()
    
    ax1.grid(True, color='w')

    plt.ylabel('Tension (lb)',color='w', fontsize=20)
    plt.title('Spiral 1 Tension',color='w', fontsize=26)

       
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='w')
    ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='w')
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)

    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    
    ax1.plot (xar,yar, 'c', linewidth=2)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10000)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to separate data pulled in on antenna 1 and 2 and plot each on the same graph (shared x axis) with different colored line plots...my attempt is here but it is not working:

```html
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from datetime import datetime
      
offset = -7.4954
slope = 0.9548

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#07000d')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='#07000d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='#07000d')

ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax1.spines['top'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax1.spines['left'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax1.spines['right'].set_color("#5998ff")

ax2.spines['bottom'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax2.spines['top'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax2.spines['left'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax2.spines['right'].set_color("#5998ff")
    
def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('SensorLog.csv','r').read()
    dataArray = graph_data.split('\n')

    xar=[]
    yar=[]
    xar2=[]
    yar2=[]    

    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if 'TimeStamp' not in eachLine: 
            if len(eachLine)>1:
                t,rc,ant,prot,rssi,epc,temp,ten,powr,unpowr,inf=(eachLine.split(','))         
                time = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
                clock = time.strftime('%I:%M')
                xs = matplotlib.dates.datestr2num(clock)
                hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y\n%I:%M:%S %p')

#                Convert tension
                tension = int(float(ten)*float(slope)+float(offset))
                              
                if ant == '1':
                    xar.append(xs)
                    yar.append(tension)
               
                if ant == '2':
                    xar2.append(xs)                    
                    yar2.append(tension)
                   
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    
    ax1.grid(True, color='w')
    ax2.grid(True, color='w')

    plt.ylabel('Tension (lb)',color='w', fontsize=20)
    plt.title('Spiral 1 Tension',color='w', fontsize=26)

       
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='w')
    ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='w')
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
   
    ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='w')
    ax2.tick_params(axis='x', colors='w')
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
   
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    
    ax1.plot (xar,yar, 'c', linewidth=2)
    ax2.plot (xar2,yar2,'r', linewidth=3)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10000)
plt.show()
```

Do you guys have any input on how I could successfully separate ant 1 and ant 2 data and plot it on the same figure in different colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply plot each data set using the same axis.

The following approach uses the Python `csv.DictReader` to help with reading in the data, along with a `defaultdict(list)` to automatically split the data into lists based on the antenna for each row.

This also adds code to addresses your comment regarding grouping data points not more than 60 seconds apart from each other, and only displaying the last 5 minutes worth of entries:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import collections
import csv

offset = -7.4954
slope = 0.9548

def plot(ax, data, colour, width):
    if data:
        last_dt = data[0][0]
        sixty = timedelta(seconds=60)

        x = []
        y = []

        # Plot groups of data not more than 60 seconds apart
        for dt, ten in data:
            if dt <= last_dt + sixty:
                x.append(dt)
                y.append(ten)
            else:
                ax.plot(matplotlib.dates.date2num(x), y, colour, linewidth=width)
                x = [dt]
                y = [ten]

            last_dt = dt

        ax.plot(matplotlib.dates.date2num(x), y, colour, linewidth=width)


def animate(i, fig, ax):
    # Read in the CSV file
    data = collections.defaultdict(list)
    fields = ["TimeStamp", "ReadCount", "Antenna", "Protocol", "RSSI", "EPC", "Temp", "Ten", "Powr", "Unpowr", "Inf"]

    with open('SensorLog.csv') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True, fieldnames=fields)
        header = next(csv_input)

        # Separate the rows based on the Antenna field
        for row in csv_input:
            try:
                data[row['Antenna']].append(
                    [datetime.strptime(row['TimeStamp'], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'), 
                    int(float(row['Ten']) * float(slope) + float(offset))])
            except TypeError as e:
                pass

    # Drop any data points more than 5 mins older than the last entry

    latest_dt = data[row['Antenna']][-1][0]     # Last entry
    not_before = latest_dt - timedelta(minutes=5)

    for antenna, entries in data.items():
        data[antenna] = [[dt, count] for dt, count in entries if dt >= not_before]

    # Redraw existing axis
    ax.clear()

    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color("#5998ff")
    ax.spines['top'].set_color("#5998ff")
    ax.spines['left'].set_color("#5998ff")
    ax.spines['right'].set_color("#5998ff")

    hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y\n%I:%M:%S %p')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    plot(ax, data['1'], 'c', 2)     # Antenna 1
    plot(ax, data['2'], 'r', 3)     # Antenna 2

    ax.grid(True, color='w')
    plt.ylabel('Tension (lb)', color='w', fontsize=20)
    plt.title('Spiral 1 Tension', color='w', fontsize=26)

    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='w')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='w')

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#07000d')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='#07000d')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(fig, ax), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

This would give you the following kind of output:

[image: demo plot]

Comment: Martin this is great - definitely the right way to go with this, thanks! Now I have another issue that popped up though and I think I can resolve it with this csv function in Python. A row of data that is a "successful" read has 11 values (separated by commas); however if the sensor is taken away from the antenna it may still get stray readings from it which don't send back all 11 values, causing an error in the attempt to read `Ten` . Where could I put an IF statement to filter out csv lines which don't have 11 values?

Comment: Also is there a way to prevent matplotlib from automatically connecting two points of data from the same antenna with a line if at least 60 seconds has passed since the last data point? I get this annoying interpolated linear line which will appear if the sensor goes out of read distance and comes back in 2 minutes later - this shows an increase in tension which didn't occur, I'd rather just have this data gap be empty. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the script to skip missing `Ten` field entries. To disconnect the data > 60 seconds apart, you would need to group the data and do a plot for each group.

Comment: I realized that sometimes the "(Infinity%)" of the last column is read as the Ten value - needless to say I put in a `try:` before `data[row['Antenna']]` and an `except: pass` after which I think effectively skips lines that don't have all the data values? If that's the case then perfect!

Hmm...grouping the data and doing a plot for each group. I'm a bit lost on how I would go about doing this. Any more help on this end?

Comment: That would be better given your data.

Comment: I have added a possible approach for grouping the data.

Comment: Martin, just noticed you put the code together for the 60 second gaps to be ignored. This works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Now the only thing left which I need to figure out is how to stop the x-axis from constantly growing with new data, but instead to only show the last 5 minutes of data. It is fixed with a 5 minute range, and any data taken more than 5 minutes ago is pushed off the graph. As you can tell I am terribly new to Python and each tiny little detail I've wanted to add has taken hours of research. You've been a great help to me so far!

Comment: Martin, I've had some success running the code with the 60 second gap data grouping, however sometimes I try to run it and I get this error: `    last_dt = data[0][0]
IndexError: list index out of range`   

Any ideas on why?

Comment: That would be because your data had no data points for one of the antenna. I have added a test for this. It also now only display the last 5 minutes worth of data.

Comment: Amazing! Wow thanks so much Martin!!! I really want to play around with Python more, it's amazing what you can do with it, I just have self-taught experience from the past couple of weeks and am struggling.  

I was trying to add a legend just now and had errors pop up. Tried adding labels 'code' plot(ax, data['1'], 'c', label='Top Tier', 2) 'code'   and then adding 'code' plt.legend(loc='lower right') 'code' right before 'code' plt.show() 'code' at the end, however received errors. Because of the dual sets of data is there a different way I have to do this?

Comment: I'm glad you liked the answer, don't forget to click on the grey tick to the side of the answer to accept it as the solution. With regards the labels, I suggest you create another question, try and make it as small and self contained as possible (i.e. you don't need the csv stuff) so you will get  more replies.

Comment: Can't seem to check it as the solution - says I need more reputation points. I will once I have enough though! Thanks!

Comment: You probably can't click the upvote button yet, but you can click the tick itself. You should also get a badge for doing it.